# Unsure how to remove whitespace from strings

Tags: python, python-3.6, removing-whitespace

```
current_price = int(input())
last_months_price = int(input())


print("This house is $" + str(current_price), '.', "The change is $" +
      str(current_price - last_months_price) + " since last month.")
print("The estimated monthly mortgage is ${:.2f}".format((current_price * 0.051) / 12), '.')
```

This produces:

```
This house is $200000 . The change is $-10000 since last month.
The estimated monthly mortgage is $850.00 .
```

I am uncertain how to remove the white space after `"$200000"` and `"$850.00"`. I don't fully understand the `strip()` command, but from what I read, it wouldn't be helpful for this problem.

Comment: Remove the `,` ? and use `f-strings` like `print(f"This house is ${current_price}. The change is ${current_price - last_months_price} ..")`

Comment: Your last `print()` call currently has two arguments. The first being the sentence `"The estimated ..."`, second being a `"."`. If you feed `print` multiple arguments, they are separated by a space. The fix is to put the dot inside the first argument: `"...mortgage is ${:.2f}>>.<<".format(..)`

Comment: [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) will remove trailing whitespace characters.

Comment: @martineau the white space in this case comes from print not from the string, otherwise tyou would be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try f-string injection

```py
print(f"This house is ${current_price}. The change is ${current_price - last_months_price} since last month.")
```

[f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (formatted strings)  provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using a minimal syntax.  It's a simplified way to concatenate strings with out having to explicitly call `str` to format data types other than strings.

As @Andreas noted below, you could also pass `sep=''` to `print`, but that requires you to concatenate other strings with the spaces properly formatted.

Comment: @JoshuaBeirl Updated.  f-strings create very concise and readable lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can give print an additional parameter: `sep`, like this:

```
print("This house is $" + str(current_price), '.', "The change is $" +
      str(current_price - last_months_price) + " since last month.", sep='')
```

because the default is an empty space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```py
print("This house is $" + str(current_price), '.',' ' "The change is $" +
      str(current_price - last_months_price) + " since last month.", sep='')
print("The estimated monthly mortgage is ${:.2f}"'.'.format((current_price * 0.051) / 12))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).